# JS: Move items in array with fixed position items

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array

```
[ {name: "A", isMoveable: true},
  {name: "B", isMoveable: true},
  {name: "C", isMoveable: false},
  {name: "D", isMoveable: true},
  {name: "E", isMoveable: false}
]
```

I have drag and drop
so we need an algorithm that moves elements, those with isMoveable: true
while keeping elements with isMoveable: false at the same indexes
for example, if I move A before C, it will be like this
`[B,A,C,D,E]`
if A in place of D, then
`[D,B,C,A,E]`

Comment: Still don't get it. If A *in place of* D it's no problem you swap them. But first you said A *before* C so that is different logic?

Comment: Is it possible the OP means "if I move A **after** C" ??

Comment: This is just a swap logic. `const AObject = arr[index of A]; arr[index of A] = arr[index of B]; arr[index of B] = AObject`